# How do I make a wait statement in Lua?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I have been using Luau (a scripting language derived from Lua) in Roblox Studio and it has a `wait()` function, but Lua does not. How do I wait in a loop? I use Lua when I'm offline from Roblox Studio to plan my code. How do I use a `wait()` statement in Lua?

This is the code I have tried so far. It does not work. This is what I would do in Luau in Roblox Studio, but I'm not sure how to use a wait statement in regular Lua.

```lua
while true do
wait()
-- code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list of sleep/wait functions [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction).

One of the easiest to implement is using [os.clock()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.8).

```lua
function sleep(s)
  local ntime = os.clock() + s/10
  repeat until os.clock() > ntime
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [luasocket](https://github.com/lunarmodules/luasocket) which lets you call `socket.sleep(seconds)` which works
across linux/windows